# Почему не выводит в селект данные и таблицы?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

накидал запрос

```
queryBuilder
      .select([
        'o.id',
        'o.phone',
        'p.id as pid',
      ])
      .leftJoinAndSelect("products", "p", "p.id = o.product_id")
      .orderBy('o.createdAt', pageOptionsDto.order ?? 'DESC')
      .skip(pageOptionsDto.skip)
      .take(pageOptionsDto.take);
```

но почему-то не выводит данные из таблицы products

вот что query выдает

```
SELECT "o"."id" AS "o_id", "o"."phone" AS "o_phone", "p"."id" AS "p_id", "p"."image" AS "p_image", "p"."image_src" AS "p_image_src", "p"."title" AS "p_title", "p"."description" AS "p_description", "p"."seo_title" AS "p_seo_title", "p"."seo_description" AS "p_seo_description", "p"."text" AS "p_text", "p"."price" AS "p_price", "p"."is_published" AS "p_is_published", "p"."slug" AS "p_slug", "p"."created_at" AS "p_created_at", "p"."updated_at" AS "p_updated_at", "p"."id" as pid FROM "orders" "o" LEFT JOIN "products" "p" ON  "p"."id" = "o"."product_id" AND "p"."deleted_at" IS NULL WHERE "o"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "o"."created_at" DESC
```

это что выводит запрос

```
[ Order { id: 1, phone: '123' } ]
```

Comment: а так `....leftJoinAndSelect("products", "p").where("p.id = o.product_id")...`?

Comment: `'p.id as pid'` не нужно, напишите `'p.id'`. и, возможно, на orderBy у вас будет ошибка

Comment: все ровно не выводит

Comment: у меня связь 1 к 1 в OrderEntity вот так @OneToOne(() => Product)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'product_id' })
  product: { Product };

Comment: `product: { Product };` а зачем тут скобки? Из-за них скорее всего проблемы

Comment: убрал, но все ровно

Answer (score 0):

это мой был косяк я вызывал getRawAndEntities(

а как выводить в camelCase

```
.select([
        'o.id as orderId',
        'o.phone',
        'p.id as productId',
      ])
```